# How can I change the content of a div when it rolls over a fixed div underneath?

Tags: html

ok so I'm looking to change the content within div.a while rolling over div.b underneath.
Like an image list scrolling over a bar with the title being displayed as it rolls over.

Please help, Mark

Comment: Please include HTML. Thanks, Brian P.S. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: hmm..actually..are the div's nested?

Answer (score 0):

This is overly simplistic, but just to give you the idea.

//jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('a#trigger').hover(){function(){
        $('h1')html('<p>first content</p>');
    },function(){
        $('h1').html('<p>second content</p>');
    }};
});
```